LaTeX Error: File `sn-jnl.cls' not found - Springer Nature Journal Template
I just downloaded the Springer Nature LaTeX Template. However, before even typing anything the .tex file fails to compile, showing the error message:

LaTeX Error: File `sn-jnl.cls' not found

I am using Texifier on MacOS. The file sn-jnl.cls is in the same directory as the .tex file I am trying to compile - i.e. I did not change or add any directories, nor did I move files etc. Everything is in the exact same folder in exactly the way the folder was provided by Springer.
I do not know how to fix that issue. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Does it work if you compile from terminal?

Please edit your posting to show a minimum working example that generates the error.
